# How do I turn off the View | Reading pane for Outlook folder?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I have this code to create a folder in Outlook from Excel. How do I set the `View | Reading pane` to 'off'?

```
Set olFolders = olSourcefolder.Parent.Folders
olFolders.Add "Audits-Actuals"'how do i set the reading pane to off?
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is possible but you need to do something first

1. Open Outlook
2. Create a View (Let's call it "**RPO**")
3. Then run this code

**Screenshot to create the view**

[image]

```
Public Sub CreateAndApplyView()
    Dim ol As New Outlook.Application
    Dim CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim NewFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set CurrentFolder = ol.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set NewFolder = CurrentFolder.Folders.Add("Audits-Actuals")

    '~~> What you need is from here. You need to activate the folder 
    '~~> before you activate the view
    Set CurrentFolder = NewFolder
    ol.ActiveExplorer.SelectFolder CurrentFolder
    ol.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView = "RPO"
End Sub
```

And this is what I get after running the code.

**[image: Screenshot]**

Comment: Rout that certainly does work, thank you! BUT... the idea is for it to happen automatically for any user when running the code for the first time. This will definitely come in handy when future folder are added IF they take the steps to prep for it but my goal is for it to just magically happen. Please let me know if you have any other ideas but for sure this is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Turning off the Preview Pane can also be done in VBA without needing to create a new view.

```
Sub HidePreviewPane() 
   Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 
   Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer 
   If myOlExp.IsPaneVisible(olPreview) = False Then 
       myOlExp.ShowPane olPreview, True 
   End If 
   Set myOlExp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.ispanevisible